# How to detect URL change through Angular 2 website in UIWebView swift?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, angular2-routing, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using UIWebView which load a URL of the website which uses Angular 2 platform. When it loads a new URL (via Angular 2 routing) then that URL isn't detecting by UIWebView delegate. How can I detect if URL change in the inside the Website via UIWebviewDelegate?

Thanks.